# Alternative Function Method of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in php css html

Tags: php, html, ios, css, objective-c

In objective-c a table view method "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" in which we can see only display value If we scroll down current display value disappeared and new value replace the current value. It is used for decreasing memory consumption. (May I wrong)

Now I have a table in php(css,html) which contains huge records. In my view I can see the record in order as "Last Insert Data".

My question is " Is any function or method in php which works like as objective-c". If any, suggest me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put pagination in records ? lets say load only 10 records and put `Load More` button at the end.

Comment: I have do this already. But what I asked I seem it is better to me.